# MySQL if statement on left join

Tags: mysql, database, join

I'm rewriting old code that returns data, and related attribute data.

The psudo logic of the old code:

```
SELECT * FROM Table;
foreach records 
    if record.col1 == '1'
        SELECT * FROM Table1;
        SELECT * FROM Table2;
    elsif record.col1 == 'A'
        SELECT * FROM TableA;
        SELECT * FROM TableB;
```

In the example below ( excuse my crude E.R.D ), Table has a One-to-one relationship with either Table1 & TableA, separately.

Table1 has a One-to-many relationship to Table2.

TableA has a One-to-many relationship to TableB.

[ Table ] --- [ Table1 ] --< [ Table2 ]

[ Table ] --- [ TableA ] --< [ TableB ]

I'm wrting a procedure to return all rows of Table, along with additional data from its relationships, if available.

I've managed to achieve the first example relationship using LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT Table.col1, Table.col2, Table1.*, Table2.*
FROM Table
LEFT JOIN Table1
  ON Table1.col3 = Table.col3
  AND Table1.col4 = Table.col4
  AND Table1.col1 = Table.col5
LEFT JOIN Table2
  ON Table1.col1 = Table2.col6
```

What i'm stuck with now is how to phrase an IF style using a JOIN of some type. I've used LEFT JOIN as i wish for all rows from Table, and only matching rows from Table1 & Table2.
In my head i've got somthing like

```
SELECT Table.col1, Table.col2, Table1.*, Table2.*
    FROM Table
    IF Table.col1 = '1'
      LEFT JOIN Table1
        ON Table1.col3 = Table.col3
        AND Table1.col4 = Table.col4
        AND Table1.col1 = Table.col5
      LEFT JOIN Table2
       ON Table1.col1 = Table2.col6
    ELSE Table.col1 = 'A'
       LEFT JOIN TableA
        ON TableA.col3 = Table.col3
        AND TableA.col4 = Table.col4
        AND TableA.col1 = Table.col5
      LEFT JOIN Table2
       ON TableA.col1 = TableB.col6
```

The above is invalid, but thats my current mind set. Could i potentially use a UNION, and include a `WHERE Table.col1 = '?'` on each side of the union?

Comment: Why not try and see.